# 平均的な新規メッセージ数とバーストの確率に基づいて、メッセージボックスがいっぱいになる時期を予測する問題

Tags: 数学, capacity-planning

予測問題ですが、最大容量を持っているメッセージボックスがあり、ユーザーが毎日このボックスにメッセージを入れているとします。毎日の新しいメッセージの数が記録されるので、履歴データによって、1日あたりの平均的な新規メッセージ数を知っております。また、ユーザーがいつよりも、10倍や100倍など大量のメッセージを送信する「バースト」があると考える必要があります。

メッセージボックスがフルになるまでかかる時間を予測したいんですが、このような変数を仮定すると、

- `C` = メッセージボックスの残りの容量
- `n` = バーストのない日の平均的な新規メッセージ数
- `burst_i` = レベル`i`のバースト、例：`burst1`= 50は、その日に50件の新しいメッセージが届くことを意味します
- `Pr(burst_i)` = `burst_i`の確率
- `Pr(no_burst)` = バーストのない確率

```
C <= T×Pr(no_burst)×n + T×Pr(burst_1)×burst1 + T×Pr(burst_2)×burst2 + ...
```

という算式を導くことができます。

これらのバーストはまれであるため、`burst_i`はポアソン分布に従うと仮定して、`T`は`T`日後にメッセージボックスがいっぱいになることを意味します。

この算式で、メッセージボックスがいっぱいになる時期を予測できますか？

Comment: formulationが明確でないので確認したいのですが、Pr(no_burst)はT日間すべてバーストがない確率ですか? それともPr(no_burst)はある特定の1日にバーストがない確率でしょうか?
同様にPr(burst_i)はT日間のすべてburst_iなのか1日だけバーストなのか(またはいずれかでもないのか)明確にしてほしいです。
そのformulationによりますが提示された算式は不十分だと思われます